# What is the purpose of 'list' function before the filter function?

Tags: python

What is the purpose of 'list' function before the filter function?

```
# Program to filter out only the even items from a list
my_list = [1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 11, 3, 12]

new_list = list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0) , my_list))

print(new_list)
```

Comment: To convert the result of calling `filter` to a list.

Comment: `filter` returns an iterator. `list` consumes the elements yielded by that iterator, and puts them in a collection - a list.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No
And please explain it to me in a different way because I didn't understand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you didn't understand. Have you tried removing `list()`? Did you see that there was a difference?

Comment: Yes now I understand, it returns: <filter object at 0x0000016E58950D60>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list() function takes the iterator object that is returned by filter(), consumes it and writes it into a list. Thus you can also do things like new_list[10] and len(new_list) which would not be possible without the list() function.

Answer (score 2):

Because in python 3+ [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterable not a list. Although it is more prefered to use a list comprehension for these situations as they are faster and easier to read.

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if not x % 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

It converts an iterator to a `list`, similar to `int`, `str`, `float`, etc.